# How can I choose only specific fields for mailchimp lists members for results

Tags: php, mailchimp

When I tried to get all the members from a list, I received more data then I needed.

I want to minimize the return json for only 4 fields, but it's seems that the 'fields' parameter doesn’t really do something.

Here my code:

```
$list_id = $this->_job->getListId();
$list =  $this->_MailChimp_obj->get('lists/' . $list_id . '/members', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'id',
        'email_address',
        'subscribed',
        'merge_fields'
    ),
    'count' => 50,
    'offset' => 0
));
```

I use this API:
https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming in late, you have to prepend "**members.**" at start of each individual field (element of array here), as there is no clear example given in the API Reference, the above code would look like

```
$list_id = $this->_job->getListId();
$list =  $this->_MailChimp_obj->get('lists/' . $list_id . '/members', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'members.id',
        'members.email_address',
        'members.subscribed',
        'members.merge_fields' //members.merge_fields.any_subfield_name
    ),
    'count' => 50,
    'offset' => 0
));
```

Furthermore if you are using Node.js with MailChimp marketing API, the code would be:

```
const mailchimp = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");

mailchimp.setConfig({
  apiKey: "your api key",
  server: "your server prefix",
});

const listId = "your list id";
const offset = 0;
const count = 10;

const run = async () => {
  const response = await mailchimp.lists.getListMembersInfo(listId, {
    offset,
    count,
    fields: ['members.id','members.email_address','members.subscribed','members.merge_fields'],
  });

  console.log(response);
  
};

run();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend the fields with "member.". If you take a look at the raw JSON output, it is more clear why - the items are returned in an enclosing "members" item.